# Is it possible to create a proxy voting form in a Salesforce Object?

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, pageblocksection, capture-forms

I have created an object called 'Shareholders' and for every Shareholder record I would like to capture their votes.

I need to create a table like below (per record) where I can capture their vote(s) per resolution, and where it is easy to update or add any new resolutions.

I have added a Resolutions Object (Parent) and a Voting Object (Child).
So in the Resolution object, every record represents a resolution.
Then I display these resolutions using a datatable (lwc) on the Vote object.
I have added a Voting field on the Vote object, but I can't find a way to store the vote under its' respective resolution.
How can I add a vote column to the datatable that sits separately from the Resolution object and can store a vote for each resolution?

It would be useful if Salesforce had a collection or list data type that you could create on a record.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Questions of the form "can I do X?" (the answer is typically yes) and "how do I accomplish broad task Y?" aren't really good fits for this site. The stackexchange model is geared towards specific questions and authoritative answers. Things that require discussion or rely too much on opinion don't work well with the Q/A format. If you can make your question much more narrow, include plentiful detail, and show us what you've tried so far, then you should [edit] your question to include that.

Comment: If you're new to Salesforce (or a feature/concept thereof), then https://trailhead.salesforce.com is a better place for you to start your journey. You may also want to consider hiring a consultant to help you with the design and execution of your project.

Comment: Sounds like you want an object for the Resolution (Ballot?) and then another object, with a master-detail relationship to Resolution, called Vote. Make sure each user can only vote once, and then you can use a roll up summary to auto-tally the votes.

Comment: Thanks nbrown, I have done this and placed a lwc datatable on the Shareholder object that updates the Voting object.